# BizTalk 2006 ESB - Is there a WcfCustom adapter?

Tags: wcf, biztalk, esb

We are implementing the Microsoft ESB Guidance on top of BizTalk 2006.  One of our major players in the business is SAP, which is catered for out of the box using BizTalk's WcfCustom adapter.

Does anybody have any advice or experience using the ESBG adapters to connect to SAP for submission of iDocs?

Will I need to write my own ESB Adapter Provider to implement the Wcf-Custom behaviour, or is there an open source alternative out there?

Cheers.

Comment: Not sure I 100% understand your question.  The ESB guidance doesn't include any adapters.  ESB guidance includes several helper type services and components to allow for more dynamic messaging patterns.  You can still use the same custom WCF adapter you would normally use.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to disambiguate my question a little.  

The MS ESB Guidance package comes with a set of "Adapter Providers", one for each protocol supported out-of-the-box, this includes WcfBasicHttp, and WcfWSHttp.

I am currently thinking I will need to roll my own Adapter Provider specifically for the WcfCustom configuration.  My understanding is that this protocol is supplied in the ESBG 2.0 package, but we are currently having to go forward with 1.x

Am currently investigating using a Messaging only solution for routing it to SAP instead.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Yeah I would look into a message only solution as to avoid rolling your own adapter provider.  Try to use as much "out of the box" functionality as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bryan, we ended up going with a messaging solution, which has worked with our initial proof-of-concept, but leaves us with a 1:1 relationship between SAP send ports and the iDoc message formats, as we need to inject an iDoc specific SOAP Header in the Send Port.
I will investigate further.